# Show spinning wheel while seeking in Jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer

Can't seem to find a way to show spinning wheel when buffering after seeking in MPEG-DASH, it doesn't show on the demo either so I guess it's a player thing...

Comment: can you share link ? or code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JW Player has a built in buffer icon on .jw-state-buffering. You can configure it using the CSS skinning reference: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/css-skinning/skins_reference/

If this isn't working for you, could you post a link or your setup code here?

Comment: Hi Josie, thanks for your comment, it was actually a problem with the video hosting provider and how the packages were delivered so jwplayer was "confused" and didn't show the buffering icon while buffering. We ended up changing provider.